# How to limit image upload option?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'am trying to limit the option to upload images in a Google Form to images captured by camera only. Basically I'm trying to remove the options "Photo library" and "Browse".

image upload options

[image: image upload options]

I was wondering if using some Google Apps Script could help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't think that would be possible with Google forms.

Comment: That does not have anything to do with Google Forms not Apps Script but by the options your phone has to upload files. Depending on the device used (phone, tablet, laptop) this will vary.